# Laravel sum/subtract of two columns based on another column

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

```
+--+-------------+--------+------+------------+
|id|product_price|quantity|status|warehouse_id|
+--+-------------+--------+------+------------+
|1 |20.00        |2000    |1     |1           |
+--+-------------+--------+------+------------+
|1 |30.00        |3000    |1     |2           |
+--+-------------+--------+------+------------+
|1 |40.00        |4000    |1     |2           |
+--+-------------+--------+------+------------+
|1 |50.00        |5000    |2     |2           |
+--+-------------+--------+------+------------+
```

I have a sales tables that has the above columns

status = 1 means the products are delivered

status = 2 means the products are returned

I have a Warehouse model that has a sales method

```
public function sales () {
    return $this->hasMany(Sale::class);
}
```

What I want?

I want to get the total income for each warehouse

Expected results:

For warehouse of id 1 `sum = 20*2000`

For warehouse of id 2 `sum = 30*3000 + 40*4000 - 50*5000`

I've tried using `withSum()` but it seems to be difficult to do the eloquent way. Is there anything I can do about it?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using `DB::raw()`. But it would be more efficient to add a generated column to your migration to get the total and use `withSum()` on that.

```php
// Add something like this to the migration
$table->unsignedBigInteger('total')->storedAs('product_price * quantity');


// Then you can do
Warehouse::withSum('sales', 'total')->get();
```

Comment: But this won't solve the status problem